# Outer loop only firing once

Tags: php, javascript, loops

I have what (to me) looks like a pretty basic nested loop. Except the outer loop is only firing the first time:

```
var js_recipes = <?php echo json_encode($recipesArray); ?>;
console.log("there are " + js_recipes.length + " recipes"); //console confirms 2

for (var i = 0; i < js_recipes.length; i++) {
    console.log("adding recipe"); //only fires once
    js_recipe = js_recipes[i];

    //add each ingredient
    for (var i = 0; i < js_recipe.ingredients.length; i++) {
        console.log("adding ing"); //fires multiple times for first recipe
    };
};
console.log("looping complete");//fires ok
```

The console output is:

```
There are 2 recipes
adding recipe
adding ing
adding ing
adding ing
adding ing
looping complete
```

I must be missing something simple, but why am I only iterating over the first recipe?

Comment: Maybe you should call your loop variable `i` something else in the inner loop?

Comment: JSlint would have caught this.  Use JSLint.  Harsh but downvote for poor research effort.

Comment: haha thanks - Not sure what more was expected, I spent an hour or so stripping my issue down to isolate the problem and then searched a while. I'll get over it.

Comment: +1 to offset the -1. This is a non-obvious idiosyncracy of JS, and is a common mistake for new programmers. Also, it's impossible to google and I didn't even know about JSLint/JSHint until nearly a year of JS programming professionally so I don't expect it as a pre-req.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scope of a variable is [either the global scope or the function where it is declared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), so you have only one `i` in this code and `i` is incremented by the inner loop as well as the outer loop.

Use different iterator variables for the different loops.

```
for (var i = 0; i < js_recipes.length; i++) {
    console.log("adding recipe");
    js_recipe = js_recipes[i];

    //add each ingredient
    for (var j = 0; j < js_recipe.ingredients.length; j++) {
        console.log("adding ing"); 
    };
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. Too much time using fast enumeration in objective-C I guess. Also over reliance on code completion.

Comment: JavaScript scope isn't really natural so you can be excused for this error the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same variable `i`. Because of [***variable hoisting***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), both of those declarations become one. Thus `i` get's incremented twice on each pass ...

Answer (score 0):

Might try setting the inner for loop to be a different variable than i, such as j, in the event there is a function variable scope issue.